# MS Excel vba number formatting

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to set a format to a UserForm textbox so that it automatically changes the numbers from 123456789.123456789 to 123,456,789.123456789.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
TextBox1.Value = Format(TextBox1.Value, "#,###.##")
End Sub
```

I used this, but it round the number to 123,456,789.12 .

Is 123,456,789.123456789 possible within the VBA ? Thanks.

Comment: try `Format(TextBox1.Value, "#,##0.000000000")`

Comment: but if you enter the number like this 123456789.12345 it will update to  this 123,456,789.123450000

Comment: I have seen how does this work in other applications (maybe not VBA) and I try to create something like that in my code ))

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many # as you want to specify the number of figures after the dot. In your case you can use a format

```
Format(TextBox1.Value, "#,###.#########")
```

Should work.

Comment: Yes it should cuts the 0s.

Comment: it doesn't cut the 0s ((

Comment: It has the proper behavior in excel on my side. I don't see why it would be different in VBA. Try formatting in general first `"General"` and then reformat again maybe.